# How to access params[:name] from the front-end inside of a class in the back-end

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How do I access my `session[:name]` which is located in the front-end of my Sinatra app, inside of a class that I have in the back-end? I want to do this so I can store all my messages (that people are saying) inside of a class to be able to quickly change my back-end messages so I can change it if wanted without having to shift through the whole front-end to code them there.

Here is the front-end part:

```
post '/startgames' do

  play = params[:playgame]
  session[:name] = params[:name]
  session[:age] = params[:age].to_i

  if play == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game" && session[:age] > 17 
    erb :trippygame1, :locals => {:message1 => "Great #{session[:name]} you are old enough to Play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game.",
                      :message2 => "One day #{session[:name]} is sitting around Smoking a bong when someone knocks on the door.", 
                      :message3 => "Do you get up and answer it?"}
  elsif play == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game" && session[:age] < 17 
    erb     erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{session[:name]} You are to young to play Joe's Trippy game how about a nice Lepoard adventure game?", :age => ""}
  elsif play == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game" && session[:age] < 17
    erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{session[:name]} Chose to play Jade's Safari Adventure Game.", :age =>""}
  else play == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game" && session[:age] > 17
    erb :safari1, :locals => {:age => "Hey man Aren't You a little old to play this type of game?",
                  :message1 => "#{session[:name]} Chose to play Jade's Safari Adventure Game."}
  end
end
```

Here is the back-end part:

```
class Start_messages


  def welcome
    "Welcome To Joe's Games."
    end

  def name_age
    "Enter your name & age to start."
    end

  def to_start_jade
    "So you wanna play Jade's Safari Adventure game ?"
  end


  def to_start_joe
    "If you want to play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game"
  end

  def start_joe
      "Great #{session[:name]} you are old enough to Play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game."
  end

end
```

I really want to be able to keep all the messages in a class rather than hard coded in the front-end. Plus, it will be easier on me to test them in the back-end as I haven't started to test the front-end stuff yet.... Im learning TDD so tests tests tests :)

Comment: Sounds like all you need is parameterized messages, e.g., search for "sinatra i18n" or roll your own less-complex solution, e.g., instead of simple strings, your messages would be templates, or methods you pass params to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dave What you suggested put me into the right direction. This is what I did incase it will help someone else. This part is  for the backend

```
def start_joe(name)
    "Great #{name} you are old enough to Play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game."
end

def start_jade(name)
    "#{name} Chose to play Jade's Safari Adventure Game."
end

def too_young(name)
    "#{name} You are too young to play Joe's Trippy game how about a nice Lepoard adventure game?"
end

def too_old(name)
    "Hey #{name} Aren't You a little old to play this type of game?"
end
```

For the front end.

```
 post '/startgames' do

play = params[:playgame]
session[:name] = params[:name]
session[:age] = params[:age].to_i
name = session[:name]
if play == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game" && session[:age] > 17 
        erb :trippygame1, :locals => {:message1 => message.start_joe(name),
                                      :message2 => "One day #{session[:name]} is sitting around Smoking a bong when someone knocks on the door.", 
                                      :message3 => "Do you get up and answer it?"}
elsif play == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game" && session[:age] < 17 
        erb     erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => message.too_young(name) , :age => ""}
elsif play == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game" && session[:age] < 17
        erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => message.start_jade(name), :age =>""}
else play == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game" && session[:age] > 17
        erb :safari1, :locals => {:age => message.too_old(name),
                                  :message1 => message.start_jade(name)}
   end
end
```

Still a work in progress now but thanks for the suggestion which makes complete sense now I don't know why I didn't think of this